# rospack deps-msgsrv

Tags: rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently updated to Diamondback. Attempting to build my package, and rosmake/make fails during a rospack deps-msgsrv call, as (according to the usage message that pops up) there no longer is a rospack desp-msgsrv command.

Suggestions? Do I have some kind of conflict between cturtle scripts and Diamondback implementation of rospack?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10552/rospack-deps-msgsrv/) by [tetracanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/816/tetracanth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) on 2011-07-11**:
Can you paste in the exact command that you try and the error that you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you run a "make clean" on the package before trying to rebuild under diamondback? If there is anything left from cturtle, that may cause a problem.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tetracanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/816/tetracanth/) on 2011-07-12**:
Perfect. Worked like a charm, and so simple I'm kicking myself for not thinking of it. Thanks.